# Bootstrap date picker specific months disable

Tags: html, date, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to get select month between April to October. I want to restrict users not to select other months except April to October. I've searched a lot but I'm unable to get such results.

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It would also be useful to show which date picker library you are using and the documentation you are trying to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getcount()
{
var text = $("#myTextArea").val();   
var lines = text.split("\n");
var count = lines.length;
console.log(count);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>


<button onclick="getcount();">GetCount</button>
```